# Correct way to create a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I have been trying to create my own jquery module, however before I make it too complex, I'm wondering if this is the 'correct' way to create it.

It's not in this demo, however the whole purpose of this is to get content via ajax, so the `data` variable returned would be an ajax response.

However, if I'm to do two separate calls like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6887S/ straight after each other, is it possible that variables, callbacks etc can be overwritten and not fired by the first call because the response is taking too long on the first one?

Please let me know if this is not the correct place to put this, just though I'd ask for help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the resource jQuery Boilerplate. http://jqueryboilerplate.com/

It has a lot of best practice guides in place. However, where you should really focus is on the actual plugin bit. https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js

You'll see a lot of good examples of using defaults, organizing your plugins logic, and other best practices as well.